# Will dynamo generate electricity with reverse spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

Will a dynamo generate electricity when it is spinning in opposite direction? If we alternate the rotation direction every minute, will it still generate electricity? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does,
A dynamo diriven in reverse simply changes the sign of the generated voltage. As a dynamo produces AC and changes the sign of voltage a few time each second, you wont notice that. So even alterating the rotation every minute has close to no effect (except from having to slow down and reaccelerate a potentialy heavy axis)

Comment: You're confusing a [dynamo with an alternator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator).